# Interlacing vertex buffer data with extra efficiency

Tags: opengl-es

I am making a 2d game in opengl es 2.0

Inside are tons of rectangles defined by 4 points and one 4 component color.

I am using vertex buffer objects, and I have heard that it is efficent to interlace the data.

So like traditionally you would do

```
Corner.x
Corner.y
Corner.z
Corner.rgba
(repeat for each corner)
```

However in my situations two assumptions can be made that can probably make things faster

```
1. All the rectangles z values are 0
2. All corners of the rectangle have the same color.
```

Is it possible, and what would it look like to have a buffer object structured like this.

```
Corner.xy
Corner.xy
Corner.xy
Corner.xy
Color.rgba?
```

Is it even possible to have opengl assume that the Z is always 0? Is it possible to reuse the color like to hat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it even possible to have opengl assume that the Z is always 0?

Yes it is. Just set the component count to 2 in `glVertexAttribPointer` and the other 2 components (`z` and `w`) will be auto filled with 0 and 1 resp.

> Is it possible to reuse the color like to hat?

No it is not. Opengl (and most other graphics apis) require that each vertex is referenced by only a single index.

Comment: You could pass the color data in a constant buffer rather than vertex data. If they are all the same.

Comment: If GL ES 3.0 is a possibility, you could also use geometry instancing, but it doesn't seem to be available in GL ES 2.0 as far as I can tell from some googling.

Comment: @Ratchet freak OK I re-strategised my plan! Thank you for letting me know.  If you are willing I made a new one because I am stuck on that one, I need to get good at vertex buffers somehow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221027/how-to-write-complicated-vertex-buffers